# What is the opposite of lazy loading?

Tags: lazy-loading, loading, lazy-evaluation

Is there a common term / catch-phrase for the opposite of lazy loading?

Answer (score 46, accepted):

The oposite term for lazy loading is **eager loading.**

Eager loading is essentially computing the tasks when you ask for it.

Lazy Loading is when you only do the computation when it is required.

Answer (score 5):

I've seen the terms "Eager Loading" and "Aggressive Initialization" both used.

Answer (score 2):

I'd say that the opposite of **lazy** is **proactive loading**, i.e. loading something in advance, before it's really needed.

However it's hard to pick the opposites when you have 3 entities `{lazy, eager, proactive}`

Comment: Tiktok uses proactive loading for video's, the experience is much better when there is no loading time, you get the sense of zapping on a real tv. I made a react component that preloads youtube vids